# Drush commands not found when called from a bash script

Tags: macos, bash, php, mamp, drupal

Relevant system background:

- I'm using MAMP on OSX.
- Output of `which php` is `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/php`
- Output of `which drush` is `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/drush`
- Output of `which bash` is `/bin/bash`
- Drush commands work fine when called directly from the command line.
- $PATH = `/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin/composer:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library:/Users/me/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/drush`

The script (test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
drush status
```

The result of running `$ ./test.sh`:

```
: No such file or directoryphp5.3.14/bin/drush: line 1: /bin/bash
: command not foundbin/php/php5.3.14/bin/drush: line 9: 
: No such file or directoryphp5.3.14/bin/drush: line 12: cd: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin
: command not foundbin/php/php5.3.14/bin/drush: line 13: 
'Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/drush: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `in
'Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/drush: line 16: `  case "`uname -a`" in
```

I'm stumped. I've made sure magic quotes are off and all that. I don't know what else to look for. Oh, and the same script runs without any issues on my other laptop, which uses a practically identical setup.

Answer (score 0):

The garbled error messages indicate your source file has `\r\n` line endings. The stray carriage returns are tripping you up

Use `dos2unix` on the source file

Comment: I have already used Vim to make sure the line ending format of both the script and drush itself was "unix".